Condition in GitLab CI Runner
I just want to create not a simple condition to start the versioning script
Condition:
execute_versioning_script:
  stage: execute_versioning_script
  before_script:
    - project_url=$(echo $CI_PROJECT_URL | sed 's/https:\/\///')
    - git remote set-url origin https://oauth2:$VERSIONING_TOKEN@$project_url
  script:
    - curl --silent "https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/incubation-engineering/mobile-devops/download-secure-files/-/raw/main/installer" | bash
    - python .secure_files/main.py
  rules:
    - if: "$CI_COMMIT_TAG != null"
      when: never
    - if: "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == 'main'"
    - if: "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == 'dev'"
    - if: "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == 'hot-fix'"
    - if: "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^feature\/[A-Z]{3,8}-[0-9]{1,4}-fix$/"

But every time I got a GitLab error about incorrect yaml file.
In the end I want to start runner only on main, dev, hot-fix and feature/--fix branches when last commit does not have tag

I remove quotes for conditions and it work
execute_versioning_script:
  stage: execute_versioning_script
  before_script:
    - project_url=$(echo $CI_PROJECT_URL | sed 's/https:\/\///')
    - git remote set-url origin https://oauth2:$VERSIONING_TOKEN@$project_url
  script:
    - curl --silent "https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/incubation-engineering/mobile-devops/download-secure-files/-/raw/main/installer" | bash
    - python .secure_files/main.py
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG != null
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == 'main'
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == 'dev'
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == 'hot-fix'
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^feature\/[A-Z]{3,8}-[0-9]{1,4}-fix$/

